# Paypal subscription users: It says "We couldn't process your recurring payment" 50% of the time

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using Paypal & setting up subscriptions successfully. These subscriptions have a 24-hour trial. On launch, we have discovered that about 50% of our subscribers' payments just don't happen after 24 hours, then we get the email which is "We couldn't process your recurring payment"... "We can't process the following recurring payment. We'll try again in 5 days" yet they're fully subscribed in our dashboard, the other 50% of subscribers, it just works seamlessly. I refuse to believe 50% of subscribers don't have the funds in their accounts... so something is wrong.

[image]

Although subscribing the user seems to be working perfectly, I just thought I'd add the code used (as seen on PayPal docs - using their smart buttons.

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  style: {
    shape: 'rect',
    color: 'gold',
    layout: 'vertical',
    label: 'subscribe'
  },
  createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': '<%=planid%>'
    });
  },

  onApprove: function(data, actions) {

    var y = JSON.stringify({
      'subID': data.subscriptionID,
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/WebServices/paypalAjax.asmx/addPaypalID',
      cache: false,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: y,
      success: OnSuccess,
      error: OnError,
      timeout: 65000
    });

    function OnSuccess(data, status) {

    };

    function OnError(data, status) { // error 2

    };

    var currency = $("#currency").val();

    window.location.replace("/members/payment-success?sub=" + data.subscriptionID + "&currency=" + currency + "&cost=<%=costDL%>&product=<%=planid%>&name=<%=name%>&trial=true");
  }

}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Has anybody has this issue, and have an idea as to how I could possibly rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

The customers' cards are being declined for the buyer-not-present recurring charge. If you remove the 24-hour trial, the 50% decline rate (or whatever it ends up being, could be lower) will happen at checkout time.

Comment: It can be. If you have questions about the declines in your situation, contact PayPal's business support, https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us

Comment: I'm on it. My main worry was if I was personally doing something wrong with my code for example - hence StackOverflow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What might be happening is an authorization is placed on the card at checkout time to validate that it has funds available and then the recurring billing system attempts a new authorization+capture 24 hours later, before the first authorization clears or is voided, as it's a separate system. 24 hours is a rare use case, you might have better luck with a trial period > 3 days since that is the usual honor period for initial authorizations

Comment: I find it backward though, as Paypal literally allows you to pick the 24hour trial length in their dashboard on a dropdown when creating the subscription model, surely their code would deal with the 24hour option seamlessly? With how many businesses use Paypal, you would have thought this "bug" would have been found and fixed by now? If Paypal aren't helpful I'll either kill off the trial, or extend it like you suggest. Thanks again!

Comment: The decline decision is made by card companies, not PayPal